# Does automapper work with calculated property?

Tags: automapper

Say I have two classes:

```
public class UnitFilter
{
   public int[] LanguageIds { get; set; } = { 1 }; 
   public int LanguageId
   {
      get => LanguageIds[0];
      set => LanguageIds = new int[value];
   }
   some properties
}

public class SomeOtherFilter
{
   public int LanguageId {get;set;}
   some properties
}
```

I would like to map SomeOtherFilter to UnitFilter

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.CreateMap<SomeOtherFilter , UnitFilter>().ReverseMap();
                });

                mapper = config.CreateMapper();

var request = new SomeOtherFilter(){LanguageId = 3};
var mappedRequest = mapper.Map<UnitFilter>(request);
```

What I thought is that as the set method for UnitFilter's LangugeId property is setting the LanguageIds array, I expected this:

```
mappedRequest.LangugeId =3;
mappedRequest.LangugeIds[0] =3;
```

However, what I got was:

```
mappedRequest.LangugeId =0;
mappedRequest.LangugeIds[0] =0;
```

So is my expectation wrong or maybe something else?

Comment: my stupid bug, I think

Answer (score 0):

Calling:

```cs
var unitFilter = new UnitFilter();
```

will set single element integer array `[1]` to `LanguageIds` property, because that's the initial value you configured. Now, you have a custom setter logic for `LanguageId` property which assigns an array of zeros `n` long, where `n` is the value passed to the `LanguageId` setter. With that in mind, calling:

```cs
var unitFilter = new UnitFilter
{
    LanguageId = 2,
};
```

will set an array of two zeros `[0, 0]` to `LanguageIds` property. First, default value `[1]` is set to the `LanguageIds` as an initial value. And then, when `LanguageId` setter is triggered, a two-element integer array of zeroes `[0, 0]` is set to the `LanguageIds` property because `2` is the value passed to the setter.

Test it out on your own:

```cs
var source = new UnitFilter();
var source2 = new UnitFilter
{
    LanguageId = 2,
};

var result = mapper.Map<SomeOtherFilter>(source);
var result2 = mapper.Map<SomeOtherFilter>(source2);
```

#### Solution

Your problem lies in incorrect properties of `UnitFilter` class, not AutoMapper.

#### Final comment

Finally, allow me to give a comment on your code while I'm already writing this. What would happen if I assign value `-1` to the `LanguageId` property? What would happen if I assign `null` to the `LanguageIds` array (because I can, setter is public) and then try to get the value of `LanguageId`? See, these are small signs saying that a too complex logic is having place in your setters and getters for properties of `UnitFilter` class. If there are multiple outputs from a property getter or setter (particularly when input data validation is taking place) you should strongly consider moving that getter/setter logic to a full sized method where you can throw exceptions caused by invalid arguments etc. Of course you can do this from a property as well, but ask yourself - would you expect such behaviour from a property getter/setter or more from a method?